# Convert seconds to HH-MM with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, format, seconds

I have been using this excellent function for HH:MM:SS, but how could I modify it to return only HH:MM with either the seconds truncated or rounded.

```
function formatSeconds(seconds)
{
    var date = new Date(1970,0,1);
    date.setSeconds(seconds);
    return date.toTimeString().replace(/.*(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");
}
```

Comment: Are you willing to use third-party libraries? MomentJS is a good one to handle time and dates.

Comment: Note that if the seconds are greater than 1 day, you will get an incorrect value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using a Date to format seconds is that it can't handle times longer than 24 hours and the vagaries of Dates. Simply reformat the value as required:

```js
function formatSeconds(seconds) {
  function z(n) {return (n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n;}
  return z(seconds / 3600 | 0) + ':' + z((seconds % 3600) / 60 | 0)
}

// Some examples
[0,1,61,3600,3660,765467].forEach(function (seconds) {
  console.log(seconds + ' -> ' + formatSeconds(seconds))
});
```

No Date, no regular expression, no library, no dependencies and works in every host that ever supported ECMAScript.

Answer (score 3):

```
function formatSeconds(seconds)
{
    var date = new Date(1970,0,1);
    date.setSeconds(seconds);
    return date.toTimeString().replace(/.*?(\d{2}:\d{2}).*/, "$1");
}
```

remove the last `\d{2}` and add `?` after the first `*`

Answer (score 0):

Though ideal way would be to use `moment.js` but if you wish to use custom function, you can try something like this:

```js
function formatSeconds(milliseconds, format) {
  var dateObj = new Date(milliseconds);

  function getDoubleDigits(value){
    return ("0" + value).slice(-2)
  }
  
  var o = {
    DD: getDoubleDigits(dateObj.getDate()),
    MM: getDoubleDigits(dateObj.getMonth() + 1),
    YY: dateObj.getYear(),
    YYYY: dateObj.getFullYear(),
    hh: getDoubleDigits(dateObj.getHours()),
    mm: getDoubleDigits(dateObj.getMinutes()),
    ss: getDoubleDigits(dateObj.getSeconds())
  }
  
  var dilimeter = format.match(/[^\w]/)[0];
  return format.split(dilimeter).map(function(f){
    return o[f];
  }).join(dilimeter);
}

var today = new Date();
console.log(formatSeconds(+today, "DD-MM-YYYY"))
console.log(formatSeconds(+today, "hh:mm"))
```

Comment: Why would moment.js be "ideal"? A function to produce the required format is just 2 lines of code.

Comment: @RobG because it handles a lot more than required. OP is dealing with time so he would use this function. Then if need comes for another format, he'll write another function. I tried to make generic function, but moment has already solved issues with date and it's an overkill in my understanding to reinvent the wheel. Yes using moment just for this case is also overkill, but as a suggestion, I'd say moment is better for datetime manipulation